# How to Change Background Color of Bootstrap Navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I'm trying to change the color of a navbar coded in Bootstrap. So far, there have been built in Bootstrap classes applied to the navbar to change both the color of the background and the anchor links in it, but they have not changed the color at all. Is there something that could be done to fix this?

Here is the HTML:

```
<!-- import Bootstrap -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-white navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>    
      </button>
      <!-- <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a> -->
      <a href="index.html"><img src="fusebloomLogo.png" alt="FuseBloom logo" class="logo"/></a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#mission">Mission</a></li>
        <li><a href="#reviews">Reviews</a></li>
        <li><a href="#process">Process</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: wicht element is it ? `id="myNavbar"` ?

Comment: it's     class="navbar"

Comment: it's not changing the background color to white, as is used in class="bg-white"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.navbar-light {
    background-color: yellow !important;
    border: none !important;
    border-width:0!important;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Preetam! That did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

```
.navbar-light {
    background-color: yellow !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Preetam! Is there a way to erase the border around it...there is a black border around the navbar now.

Comment: .navbar-light {border:none;}

Comment: .navbar-light {
    background-color: yellow !important;
    border: none !important;
    border-width:0!important;
}

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked [color-boostrap v5](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/customize/color/)

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-light" style="background-color: #ffffff;">
    <!-- Navbar content -->
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

For Bootstrap v5 they have background color utilities. So you can just add one of the pre-made Bootstrap colors by adding a certain class. For example, adding the class `bg-primary` will color the background of the navbar that primary Bootstrap blue color. They also have yellow which you can add with the class `bg-warning`

Here's a link to all the available colors:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/utilities/background/

Answer (score 0):

## Tailwind Solution

All of the React Bootstrap components can be styled with TailwindCSS so you can just add a bg- color to the `className`:

```
<Navbar
        expand="lg"
        className="px-3 bg-stone-800"
      >
...

</Navbar>
```